# Why does Xcode create non-wildcard app IDs called "XC Wildcard"?

Tags: ios, xcode

I removed all my app IDs and provisioning profiles from Apple's Developer site. Then I created a new Xcode 7.3.1 project, and clicked "Fix Issue" next to the "no matching provisioning profiles found" message.

The app ID it created is called "XC Wildcard", **but it's not a wildcard ID**; it's set to the bundle identifier of the Xcode project. And the development profile it created is assigned to that app ID.

If I change the bundle identifier and click "Fix Issue", it creates a second app ID called "XC Wildcard", with the new bundle identifier, and another development profile for it.

This works, but seems wrong. Shouldn't it be creating an actual wildcard app ID, unless I turn on specific capabilities like Push Notifications?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode create "XC Wildcard" to be used for debugging so it matches all app id's

change deployment configuration from debug to release and Xcode will create a provisioning profile with your app id.

Comment: But it's not creating a wildcard app ID...it's just naming it "XC Wildcard." See above.

Comment: did you changed build configuration to Release ?

Comment: No, it's building using the debug configuration. So I would expect it to create wildcard app IDs.

Comment: yes Xcode create provisioning profile for apps if its release